# Windows Phone 7 template not found in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I have VS 2010 Professional installed on 64bit Windows 7. I installed the Windows Phone 7 developer tools, this ran fine without any hassle: I can start the emulator. However, when I try to create a project, I can't see the templates for phone development. I searched the installed templates, but they appear to be not installed. Any comments would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked under the Silverlight Option or XNA Game Studio 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

If installed correctly, they will be under:
Installed Templates > Visual C# > Silverlight for Windows Phone (for Silverlight templates)
or
Installed Templates > Visual C# > XNA Game Studio 4.0

If you can see the options in the menu, but not the templates, check the version of the .NET Framework which is selected - from the dropdown at the top of the dialog.

You could also check they are installed by looking at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Silverlight for Windows Phone\1033

If they're not there, try repairing the install or reinstalling.

Comment: indeed, after several iterations, I finally managed to install succesfully including all templates.